# Backwards stable factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

A factor $R$ is called stable if $M_n(R)\cong R$ for all $n>0$. For the sake of this question, we call a factor *backwards stable* if $R\cong M_n(S)$ implies $S\cong R$ where $S$ is allowed to be any other factor.
If $R$ is stable then it is backwards stable if $M_n(R)\cong M_n(S) \implies R\cong S$.

My question is which factors are backwards stable.

I'm particularly interested in hyperfinite type III factors. For hyperfinite type II factors I can show backwards stability using the uniqueness of the II$_1$ factor.

As a side question, are there examples of factors that are not stable other than those of finite type I? For infinite factors, one can always find Cuntz isometries so that they should be stable and, by uniqueness, the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor is stable. This leaves open the case of non-hyperfinite type II$_1$ factors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $\textrm{II}_1$ factors, your definitions of backwards stable and stable are the same. The point here is that for a $\textrm{II}_1$ factor $R$ you can talk about $M_n(R)$ for all positive number $n$ instead of just positive integers. This is called amplification and is usually written as $R^n$. This is done by choosing an integer $m \geq n$ and a projection $p$ of trace $\frac{n}{m}$ in $M_m(R)$, then defining $R^n = pM_m(R)p$. The fact that two projections of the same trace are equivalent in a $\textrm{II}_1$ factor ensures that this is well-defined and does not depend on the choice of $m$ or $p$. With this in mind, as $R = M_n(R)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, $M_n(R) \simeq M_n(S) \Rightarrow R \simeq S$ always holds for $\textrm{II}_1$ factors $R$ and $S$. As you have observed, this means stability implies backwards stability. The converse holds by observing that, if $R$ is backwards stable, as $R \simeq M_n(R^{\frac{1}{n}})$ (this is a general fact about amplifications), $R \simeq R^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Then $R \simeq M_n(R^{\frac{1}{n}}) \simeq M_n(R)$, which shows $R$ is stable.

There are plenty of non-stable $\textrm{II}_1$ factors. In fact, for a $\textrm{II}_1$ factor $R$, the collection of positive real numbers $r$ for which $R \simeq R^r$ form a group under multiplication, which is known as the fundamental group of $R$. Plenty of $\textrm{II}_1$ factors have fundamental groups that are not $\mathbb{R}_+$. For example, all property (T) $\textrm{II}_1$ factors have countable fundamental groups. They could even have trivial fundamental groups. (See, for example, chapter 18 in [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIunV15.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epopa/Books/IIunV15.pdf) .) It is a famous open question as to what is the fundamental group of the free group factor $L(\mathbb{F}_2)$, which is currently only known to be either trivial or $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the very interesting answer! I'll leave the question open for a bit longer in hope for an answer regarding the type III case.

Comment: @Lauritz For the separable type III case (or more generally for any $\sigma$-finite infinite factor), $R$ is always both stable and backwards stable. This follows from the observation that all infinite projections in a $\sigma$-finite factor are equivalent to each other. (The basic proof idea is using comparison lemma, and by changing labels and replacing by equivalent projections, we may assume $e \leq f$. Replacing the factor $R$ by $fRf$, we may assume $f = 1$. Now as $e$ is properly infinite, we may choose orthogonal $e_1, e_1’ \leq e$ such that $e_1, e_1’$ are both equivalent to $e$…

Comment: @Lauritz Applying this process repeatedly to obtain a sequence of mutually orthogonal projections $e_i \leq e$ which are all equivalent to $e$. Now choose a maximal family of mutually orthogonal non-zero projections $f_j \lesssim e$. By $\sigma$-finiteness, this family is countable. By maximality, $\sum_j f_j = 1$. Hence, $e \geq \sum_i e_i \gtrsim \sum_j f_j = 1$. So $e \sim 1 = f$.) Now using this, if $R$ is a $\sigma$-finite properly infinite factor, then so is $M_n(R)$…

Comment: @Lauritz Then in $M_n(R)$, $1$ and $e_{11}$ are both infinite and therefore equivalent. This yields an isomorphism $R \simeq M_n(R)$. Thus, $R$ is always stable. It is backwards stable as $R \simeq M_n(S)$ means $S$ is infinite, so stability of $S$ gives $R \simeq M_n(S) \simeq S$.

Comment: Another interesting thing to note is that you mentioned the hyperfinite $\textrm{II}_1$ factor. Usually we only work with separable algebras, in which case the uniqueness theorem for the separable hyperfinite $\textrm{II}_1$ factor implies it has fundamental group $\mathbb{R}_+$, so it is in particular stable. This doesn’t have to hold for non-separable hyperfinite $\textrm{II}_1$ factors. In fact, in that case it is even possible for it to have trivial fundamental group, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12727 .